# XLSX get last column?

Tags: java, webdriver, apache-poi, xlsx

How can i get the the last column when reading a xlsx file using the Apache POI API? There's a getLastRowNum method but nothing related with number of columns.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check each `Row` and call [`Row.getLastCellNum()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getLastCellNum()). The max cell num is the last column num.